# Getting "display surface Quit" error Using gymnasium library

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am getting error on running again env.reset() in jupyter notebook, and I have to make environment again to run first block of code (i.e. from episode=5...env.close())

Here is the code:

```py
import os
import gymnasium as gym
environment_name= "CartPole-v1"
env=gym.make(environment_name,render_mode="human")
episodes=5
for episode in range(1,episodes+1):
    state=env.reset()
    done=False
    score=0
    
    while not done:
        env.render()
        action=env.action_space.sample()
        n_state,reward,terminated,truncated,info=env.step(action)
        score+=reward
        done=terminated or truncated
    print('Episode:{} score:{}'.format(episode,score))
env.close()
```

```
Output:
Episode:1 score:25.0
Episode:2 score:21.0
Episode:3 score:18.0
Episode:4 score:17.0
Episode:5 score:11.0
```

I am expecting to get vector with size 4
but getting error

```
env.reset()
```

```
Output:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 1
----> 1 env.reset()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gymnasium\wrappers\time_limit.py:75, in TimeLimit.reset(self, **kwargs)
     66 """Resets the environment with :param:`**kwargs` and sets the number of steps elapsed to zero.
     67 
     68 Args:
   (...)
     72     The reset environment
     73 """
     74 self._elapsed_steps = 0
---> 75 return self.env.reset(**kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gymnasium\wrappers\order_enforcing.py:61, in OrderEnforcing.reset(self, **kwargs)
     59 """Resets the environment with `kwargs`."""
     60 self._has_reset = True
---> 61 return self.env.reset(**kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gymnasium\wrappers\env_checker.py:57, in PassiveEnvChecker.reset(self, **kwargs)
     55     return env_reset_passive_checker(self.env, **kwargs)
     56 else:
---> 57     return self.env.reset(**kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gymnasium\envs\classic_control\cartpole.py:209, in CartPoleEnv.reset(self, seed, options)
    206 self.steps_beyond_terminated = None
    208 if self.render_mode == "human":
--> 209     self.render()
    210 return np.array(self.state, dtype=np.float32), {}

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gymnasium\envs\classic_control\cartpole.py:299, in CartPoleEnv.render(self)
    296 gfxdraw.hline(self.surf, 0, self.screen_width, carty, (0, 0, 0))
    298 self.surf = pygame.transform.flip(self.surf, False, True)
--> 299 self.screen.blit(self.surf, (0, 0))
    300 if self.render_mode == "human":
    301     pygame.event.pump()

error: display Surface quit
```